# Can't push values to mongoDB array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

Hiii, I have a MEAN stack application that make use of a mongoose model defined as below:

appointment.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Appointment', {
appt_date: String,
details: [ {
            appt_time: String,
            patient_id : String,
            patient_name : String,
            contact_no: String,
            doctor_name : String,
            purpose : String
          }
      ]
});
```

I want to generate a document like the following:

```
{
 appt_date: 13/13/2013,
 details: [
    {
        appt_time: 09:00 AM,
        patient_id: 2015/2016,
        patient_name: David John,
        contact_no: 8965741234,
        doctor_name: Albert ,
        purpose: Consultation,

    }
}
```

I can't generate a document when using the following Express JS code:

```
var Appointment = require('../../models/appointment');
var appointments = new Appointment ({ "appt_date" : req.body.date});
appointments.save();
Appointment.update({ appt_date: req.body.date},
{ 
  $push: {
           'details':  {    
                         appt_time:"09:00 AM",
                         patient_id:"2015/2016",
                         patient_name:"Wilfred",
                         contact_no:"8965741234",
                         doctor_name: "Albert",
                         purpose: "Consultation"
                       }
          }
 },
   {
      upsert:true
   });
```

After performing the above operations, the result that I get is as follows:

```
"_id": ObjectId('57b6eefd2b494e802ba146d8'),
"appt_date": "12/20/2014",
"details": [],
"__v": 0
```

I am not able to push any data to the "details" array. What I am in need is a single date entry (appt_date), multiple details (details array). Please help to solve this out.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
var Appointment = require('../../models/appointment');
var appointments = new Appointment();
appointments.appt_date = req.body.date;
appointment.details.push({appt_time:"09:00 AM",patient_id:"2015/2016", patient_name:"Wilfred",contact_no:"8965741234",doctor_name: "Albert",
purpose: "Consultation"});
appointments.save(function(err){
   if(!err)
      console.log("saved")
})
```

Comment: @ Md Nazmul Bilash - Thanks. I need to create the document at an instance with appt_date and later update/push the information to the previously created document, i.e into the `details` array. i don't want to create a new document every time when a date is selected. Please help to solve this...

Comment: First Time to create a document :
 Appointment ({ "appt_date" : req.body.date});

if you want to push other inf
var appointments = newormation later then :
Appointent.find({_id : 'Id of appointment'}).exec(function(err,appoinment){
   if(appoinment){
        appointment.details.push({appt_time:"09:00 AM", patient_id:"2015/2016", patient_name:"Wilfred", contact_no:"8965741234", doctor_name: "Albert",
 purpose: "Consultation"});
appointments.save(function(err){
   if(!err)
      console.log("saved")
})
   }
})

Comment: yeah I did that. Later I tried the following code. `Appointment.update({ appt_date: req.body.date},{ $push: {
     'details':  {   
      appt_time:12,
      patient_id:1025,
      patient_name:"roger",
      contact_no:8089,
      doctor_name: "jestin",
       purpose: "RCT"
  }
 }
 },{upsert:true});`

This won't push any data to the `details` array. I even tried `_id` instead of `appt_date` to find the exact document, but failed. What is wrong with this code .. ?

Comment: I think its not saving your data. Did you called save() after update ??

Comment: inside the function to open the modal, i used the following code:
`var appointments = new Appointment ({ "appt_date" : req.body.date});`
later inside another function which pass the information (appt_time, name,id etc), i used the following code: 
`Appointment.update({ _id: req.body.id},
{ $push: {  'details':  {    appt_time:12, patient_id:1025, patient_name:"roger", contact_no:8089, doctor_name: "jestin", purpose: "RCT"
   }
  }
 },{upsert:true});`
I have the `_id` of the previously generated document inside the function. But the operation fails. Where should I correct **this** code

Comment: Did you save your code after push ? Call .save function.

IF possible please copy your code on jsfiddle, then I can help you from there. But at first try to save the data.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do an update after `save()`, just use the **[`push()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.push)** method on the `details` key and then save. For example:

```
var Appointment = require('../../models/appointment');
var appointments = new Appointment ({ "appt_date" : req.body.date});
appointments.details.push({    
    appt_time: "09:00 AM",
    patient_id: "2015/2016",
    patient_name: "Wilfred",
    contact_no: "8965741234",
    doctor_name: "Albert",
    purpose: "Consultation"
});
appointments.save(function(err, appointment){
    if (err) handleErr(err);
    console.log(appointment);
});
```

Comment: @ Chridam - Thanks ....   On execution, this always creates a new document, right ? The values mentioned inside the update command comes in a second step. What I need is - Step 1) Select a date - this should add a document with appt_date = selected date. Step 2) A form will be displayed from where the details like appt_time, patient_id and etc etc comes from. I don't want to create a new document for every entry. One date = one document, multiple details inside the "details" array. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: @ Chridam - I need to create a document upon the selection of the date with the defined model, later when the user completes the info, push those info into the "details" array. I am trying to create an appointment scheduler. So when the user selects a "date" and insert some info, and later on when the user selects the "same date" and add some info, those info should be pushed to "details" array..

Comment: @ Chridam - What I did was this: On selecting the date, I sent the date back to server and used the code 'var appointments = new Appointment ({ "appt_date" : req.body.date  });' to create a document. At the same instance a modal will be opened to where the info is provided. Upon receiving this info, I used the rest of the code 'Appointment.update({appt_date: req.body.date})'....... At this instance, the mentioned code does no work on the created document. How can I het this corrected. Creation & pushing are done at two instances.

Answer (score 0):

You are updating document against the date and might be there are more than 1 app_date, this scenario will update multiple document ., you have to add multi : true object

```
Appointment.update({ appt_date: req.body.date},
{ 
 $push: {
       'details':  {    
                     appt_time:"09:00 AM",
                     patient_id:"2015/2016",
                     patient_name:"Wilfred",
                     contact_no:"8965741234",
                     doctor_name: "Albert",
                     purpose: "Consultation"
                   }
      }
},
{multi: true},
 {
  upsert:true
 });
```

or you can update it by _id

Comment: @ Muhammad Ali - Thanks. What I need is a single document with a single appt_date and multiple entries for `details` array. appt_date is generated at an instance and i want to create a document with the mentioned model. at a later instance I need to update this document, i.e push the info to the `details` array. I don't want to create a new document every time when a date is selected. What I need is single date  entry in a document, multiple information entries in `details` array.